# Передача значений элементов вектора из одной функции в другую

Tags: c++

Дано задание: переписать первые элементы каждой строки матрицы A (m×n), большие С, в массив В. Если данный элемент меньше C, то записать ноль в массив В.

Задание необходимо выполнить, разбив части программы на функции.

Проблема в том, что после выполнения первой функции консоль выдаёт сообщение "trap" и программа завершается.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int arrIn(int M, int N, int C, vector<vector<int>> &a, vector<int> &b)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 101 - 50;
            cout << '|';
            cout.width(3);
            cout.fill(' ');
            cout << a[i][j];
            cout << '|';
        }
        cout << endl;
        if (a[i][0] > C)
        {
            b[i] = a[i][0];
        }
        else
        {
            b[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
int arrOut(int M, vector<int> &b)
{
    int i;
    cout << "Итоговый массив B: ";
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
         cout << '|';
         cout.width(3);
         cout.fill(' ');
         cout << b[i];
         cout << '|' << endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int m, n, c;
    cout << "Введите размер матрицы А (m, n): ";
    cin >> m >> n;
    cout << "Введите значение C: ";
    cin >> c;
    vector<vector<int>> a(m, vector<int>(n));
    vector<int> b(m);
    cout << endl;
    arrIn(m, n, c, a, b);
    arrOut(m, b);
    system("pause");
}
```

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если обе функции объявить как void, то работает.
Как ваш компилятор обходится с игнором возвращаемого значения - не знаю.

Вообще это [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return), как @ixSci подсказал.

> Flowing off the end of a value-returning function (except main)
>   without a return statement is undefined behavior.

Форматирование подправить: `cout << "Итоговый массив B: " << endl;`

Comment: Отсутствие `return` в функции, которая должна что-то возвращать — UB. Компилятор не обязан уведомлять об этом. `return 0` в `main` необязателен.